# Pass data to parent component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `router-link` that navigates to one of my components. It also passes a param which is then set within my component

```
created() {
    this.sentData = this.$route.params.sentData;
}
```

When I navigate to the page, I can print out the sent data, and can also see that it is set within my Vue console.  So this is all good.  On this page, I am using [vue-simple-uploader](https://github.com/simple-uploader/vue-uploader).  Just a very simple upload component.  According to the docs, you can send a query parameter along with the file to the backend.  So as a simple test, I done

```
data() {
    return {
        sentData: '',
        options: {
            //other stuff like target
            query:  function (uploaderFile, uploaderChunk) {
                return { sentData: 'Test' }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now within the backend, I can see the file, as well as the parameter sentData which contains the string Test.  So this all works.  I then tried replacing the string with

```
return { sentData: this.sentData }
```

But it complains that `this.sentData` is null, even though I can see it is present.  So I thought it must be because I am theoretically within a child component (the uploader) so I must need to obtain the data from the parent.  I have tried

```
return { sentData: $parent.sentData }
```

and

```
return { sentData: this.$parent.sentData }
```

with no success, just getting nulls.  So I was wondering how I can access this data from within the uploader component?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` context inside your `options.query` method does not really refer to the Vue instance, but the context of the method itself, to work around that, you could assign a local variable to the current instance.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  created() {
    this.sentData = 'Some initial value';
  },

  data() {
    const vm = this;

    return {
      sentData: '',

      options: {
        query(uploaderFile, uploaderChunk) {
          return {
            sentData: vm.sentData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span v-text="options.query().sentData"></span>
</div>
```